# Google guava: Using `ByteSource` and `ByteSink` after deprecation of `InputSupplier` and `OutputSupplier` utilities

Tags: java, guava, java-io

I came across old code in my project which uses `InputSupplier` and `OutputSupplier` utility from Google Guava. Since these classes are deprecated in the latest version, I need to refactor my code accordingly.

By looking on the internet I came to know that I can use `ByteSource` and `ByteSink` in place of `InputSupplier` and `OutputSupplier` by doing some minimal changes. 
The below sample represents a case where I have used ByteSink in place of `OutputSupplier`.

```java
  public static OutputSupplier<? extends OutputStream> newOutputSupplier() {
    return new OutputSupplier<OutputStream>() {
      @Override
      public OutputStream getOutput() throws IOException {
        return new FileOutputStream(file);         // file defined earlier
      }
```

After using `ByteSink`

```java
public static ByteSink newOutputSupplier() {
    return new ByteSink() {
      @Override
      public OutputStream openStream() throws IOException {
        return new FileOutputStream(file); // file defined earlier
      }
    };
  }
```

Similar refactoring for `InputSupplier` related code.

**Question 1**: Is the above refactoring is correct? am I thinking in the right direction?

**Question 2**: Can i wrap `ZipOutputStream` in `ByteSink`  ?

**Question 3**: If yes for the previous question, how will I get back the `ZipOutputStream` from `ByteSink` as it returns `OutputStream`?  Will casting work in this case as in below snippet?

```java
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = (ZipOutputStream) newOutputSupplier().openStream(); // Casting
```

Or do I need to create new `ZipOutputStream` from `OutputStream`?

```java
ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(newOutputSupplier().openStream());
```

**Question 4**: Can I wrap any kind of `InputStream` or `OutputStream`?

**NOTE**: *I have mainly given example of `OutputStream`, `ZipOutputStream` and `ByteSink` but I am doing the similar things for `InputStream`, `ZipInputStream` and `ByteSource`.*

Comment: You should probably use e.g. `Files.asByteSink`; 2) probably manually, 3) yes but you probably _shouldn't_; 4) as long as you can create a fresh one each time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman you should probably answer in an answer instead of a comment. It's totally ok to answer with the text you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should probably use e.g. Files.asByteSink.
2. I wouldn't.  `ByteSink` is intended for generic `OutputStream`s that don't have additional methods.
3. Not applicable.
4. Yes, as long as you can create a fresh one each time.

Comment: Can you please explain point 3 further ? why shouldn't ? what is the right way ? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm.  On further consideration, I've updated my answer.